# Can't access WiFi after resetting the network

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

This morning I had some connectivity issues and couldn't connect to my usual WiFi network. I thought the issue came from my computer (turns out it didn't) so I followed the Windows 10 network error diagnostic which advised me to "reset the network" (in effect, uninstalling, then reinstalling all network adapters, and resetting all parameters of other networking components). I followed the instructions and reset the network. However, now I cannot connect to or even view available WiFi networks anymore.
If you have any advice as to how to proceed to re-establish WiFi access to my computer, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Resetting the network is not the same as reinstalling drivers. Try rebooting. It should work. If not then you did something wrong.

Comment: I have tried rebooting but to no avail.

Comment: Uninstall the Wireless Network card. Do NOT restart. Run DISM / SFC  .....  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.  ..  Now restart and let Windows install the Wireless card.  Can you connect now?

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled the adapter. I tried running (2) but I am facing the following error
 Error: 0x800f0806

The operation could not be completed due to pending operations.

Comment: @grove Rebooting should clear that error, allowing you to run `Dism` and `Sfc` without issue, as that will occur if there are pending operations on the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] _(IIRC, it can also be caused by a dirty shutdown/hard reboot, as both of those sets a flag that must be cleared via a normal shutdown/reboot)_

Comment: Thank you all. I ended up fixing the problem by simply reinstalling the driver without using Dism and Sfc.